# Passing JSON Object and List of Objects to ASP.Net Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I need some help with the hereunder please. I have these 2 models and the method I will be using them in hereunder.

```
public class RoleModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<PermissionGroupModel> PermissionGroups { get; set; }
}

public class PermissionGroupModel
{
    public int PermissionGroupID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

 [HttpPost]
 public bool CreateRole(RoleModel r){
  //code goes here
}
```

I am trying to post data to the CreateRole() method via AJAX and using a debug break to inspect the 'r' parameter to see if the model is getting populated. This is the AJAX call I am using to test it out.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/BackOffice/CreateRole",
        data:  {"Name": "Test Name", "Description": "Test Desc", "PermissionGroups": ["Name": "Group Name", "Description": "Test Desc"]},
        success: function (data) {},
        complete: function (data) {}
      });
```

When the request is made and I inspect the parameter in visual studio. The RoleModel Name and Description Keys are populated and PermissionGroups Count is 1 but the keys in PermissionGroups are not being populated.

Can anyone suggest any way I can pass a JSON object with a list of objects in it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not sending the PermissionGroupID property of the PermissionGroups items, how do you expect that it will be populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript object you are sending is not proper.

```
 "PermissionGroups": ["Name": "Group Name", "Description": "Test Desc"]
```

In your viewmodel, `PermissionGroups` is a collection of `PermissionGroupModel` items. But you are not passing it like this. The above code is sending 4 string items as the value of the `PermissionGroups` property. You need to wrap each item in the collection with `{` and `}`

Also ,for model binding to happen on complex objects, you need to convert your javascript object to a json string using  `JSON.stringify` method and specify the `contentType` property when making the ajax call. The `contentType` property value should be `"application/json"`

The `contentType` property tells the server that the data we are sending is in Json format.

```
 var d = {
            "Name": "Test Name", "Description": "Test Desc",
            "PermissionGroups": [{ "Name": "Group Name", "Description": "Test Desc" }]
         };

 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/BackOffice/CreateRole",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(d) ,
            success: function (data) {  console.log(data); },
            complete: function (data) {}
       });
```

Also, It is a good idea to use the Url.Action helper method to build the urls to action methods.

So replace  `url: "/BackOffice/CreateRole"` with  `url: "@Url.Action("CreateRole","BackOffice")"`

Comment: Thanks dude this worked flawlessly !